# Combining fields and avoiding duplicate display

Tags: entities

I use below code for printing out images in search results. I get double print outs on the ALT tags. If I disable ALT tags all displays just fine.

```
<a href="<?php print $url; ?>" class="search-result-img-wrapper">
    <?php
      print theme_image_style(array(
        'style_name' => 'thumbnail',
        'path' => $result['node']->field_image['und'][0]['uri'],
        'alt' => $title,
        'attributes' => array('class' => 'search-result-img'),
      ));
    ?>
  </a>
  <a href="<?php print $url; ?>" class="search-result-img-wrapper">
    <?php
      print theme_image_style(array(
        'style_name' => 'thumbnail',
        'path' => $result['node']->field_product_image['und'][0]['uri'],
        'alt' => $title,
        'attributes' => array('class' => 'search-result-img'),
      ));
    ?>
  </a>
```

If I add fields like below, I get only the print out of one of the fields and not both.

```
<a href="<?php print $url; ?>" class="search-result-img-wrapper">
    <?php
      print theme_image_style(array(
        'style_name' => 'thumbnail',
        'path' => $result['node']->field_product_image['und'][0]['uri'],
        'path' => $result['node']->field_image['und'][0]['uri'],
        'alt' => $title,
        'attributes' => array('class' => 'search-result-img'),
      ));
    ?>
  </a>
```

What am I missing? Thanks much for your input.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this will necessarily fix your problem, but you're calling the theme_image_style incorrectly, it should be:

```
theme('image_style', array(
  'style_name' => 'thumbnail',
  'path' => $result['node']->field_image['und'][0]['uri'],
  'alt' => $title,
  'title' => $title,
  'attributes' => array('class' => 'search-result-img'),
));
```

Your second example is wrong, you can't call `path` twice.

Comment: can 2 different fields be put in a path?

Comment: No you will need to call theme('image_style', ...) twice, what does $title contain? Is it plain text or HTML? Surely, it should be $result['node']->title

Comment: thank you for your responses and input. $title contains html (ALT tag output).

Comment: If it contains HTML you will need to strip that off as plain text is expected